# Create a 'select' drop-down menu in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a problem in a simply js function. I have a web page where I show records in a table, and when I click on an icon (which stands for 'change this record'), that cell of table should be replaced with a dropdown menu in which the user can select the new value for that record based on the available ones.

I tried in a lot of ways:

```js
function clickOnModifyProfessor(id, professors) {
    let select = document.createElement("select");
    select.setAttribute("id", id);
    for (let i = 0; i < professors.length; i++) {
        let el = document.createElement("option");
        el.textContent = professors[i]['name'] + " " + professors[i]['surname'];
        el.value = professors[i]['professorID'];
        select.appendChild(el);
    }
    //I set id=2 simply to test with one specific record, if it works I'll just set another parameter to generalize the change.
    const node = document.getElementById("2");
    node.textContent = '';
    node.appendChild(select);
}
```

With this code I just get the empty table cell after clicking on the modify button, but the strange thing is that if I try to create another element (textarea, password etc) it works perfectly, so I can't understand why it does this only with the select element. I also tried by creating the whole select with option elements and taking it to the table cell by the innerHTML, but it doesn't works (as before, it works with others elements that aren't 'select').

If it can help, here is the code fragment where I call this function:

```php
echo "<tr><td>" . $row['subjectName'] . "</td>
         <td id='" . $rowsCount . "'>
            <p>" . $row['profName'] . " " . $row['profSurname'] . "
               <i class='material-icons' onclick='clickOnModifyProfessor(" . json_encode($row['subjectName'], JSON_HEX_APOS) . "," . json_encode($professors, JSON_HEX_APOS) . ")'>create</i>
            </p>     
         </td>
      </tr>";
```

PS: I also tried to print in console `document.getElementById(id).innerText` after I append the new 'select' element to the document and it prints correctly the options I added.

Am I making an error? I hope it's sufficiently clear.

Comment: I put your code in a snippet and it works just fine. YOu need to dig into troubleshooting this more bc what you've posted isn't the issue.

Comment: @Kinglish do you think it can be a problem in how I created the table? I used a materialize css class (maybe that table class doesn't support a select element in a cell, but I'm just supposing)

Comment: css shouldn't affect javascript - but look in your web inspector and add console.log statements to make sure your target element exists (the cell's ID) - get granular with it until you find the point at which it isn't working

Comment: Check the dev tools to ensure this is a JS issue and not a styling one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my own question with the solution I found, maybe it can be helpful for someone.

The problem is that the materialize css' select can't render on browser without starting js before, so it's necessary to add `class='browser-default'` when we create the select element or, if we want materialize css select style, we need to use `$('select').formSelect();` after the select element has been created with its options.